Irradiance values acquired via pvlib do not make sense
I have run my code and I get my graph. However, the values in the graph do not make any sense. Most of the time, the dni values surpass the ghi values, which is not supposed to happen. I also compared the result with the irradiation values acquired in the PVGIS and they are completely different.
import pvlib
from pvlib.modelchain import ModelChain
from pvlib.location import Location
from pvlib.pvsystem import PVSystem
from pvlib.temperature import TEMPERATURE_MODEL_PARAMETERS
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

location = Location(latitude=60.44852562172572, longitude= 22.297630788268044, tz= 'Europe/Helsinki', altitude= 30, name= 'Turku' )
print(location)

sandia_modules = pvlib.pvsystem.retrieve_sam('SandiaMod')
cec_inverters = pvlib.pvsystem.retrieve_sam('CECInverter')

module = sandia_modules['Canadian_Solar_CS5P_220M___2009_']
inverter = cec_inverters['ABB__MICRO_0_25_I_OUTD_US_208__208V_']

temperature_parameters = TEMPERATURE_MODEL_PARAMETERS['sapm']['open_rack_glass_glass']

system = PVSystem(surface_tilt=45, surface_azimuth=180, module_parameters=module, inverter_parameters= inverter, temperature_model_parameters=temperature_parameters)


modelchain = ModelChain(system, location)

times = pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01', end= '2020-01-01', freq='1min', tz= location.tz)

clear_sky = location.get_clearsky(times)

clear_sky.plot(figsize=(16,9))
plt.show()

I tried this and expected something like below:
However, my results are off the chart. My result was the following. 

Please do not post the same question in two places at once.

"Most of the time, the dni values surpass the ghi values, which is not supposed to happen." -- that is not true.  DNI often does exceed GHI.

It looks like you are ploting full year and beacause your are unable to see the shape of irradianton profiles.
Use the zoom tool or reduce the data range, example for one day you must see somethin similar to this, (is another location)
DNI-GHI-POA-DHI
